# Where should I ask command-line related questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, serverfault

Where should I ask questions related to how to do things in the Windows command line (or in Bash)? Stack Overflow, or Server Fault? I mean, like these questions:

[How to compare to text files using command line tools, under Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/250220)

[Why does the Windows command line change the command when running from a .bat file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/249624)

[Creating an MD5 file for a directory tree for only a given extension](https://serverfault.com/questions/249579)

I've just registered on Server Fault for these questions, but maybe I should have asked them on Stack Overflow. Do you think so?

Comment: SF or SU... definitely not SO!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Batch/Bash scripting is slightly on-topic at Stack Overflow, however those questions might be closed by the community.

Here's my rule of thumb:  Start at 1 and go down until you find the first match for your qestion.

1. Do you want to know how to perform some management function from the command line? **Server Fault**.
2. Do you want to know how commandlets work, or which to use?
   a. Ubuntu-specific? **askubuntu**.
   b. Unix/Linux specific? **unix.SE**.
   c. Mac specific? **apple.SE**.
   d. **Super User**.
3. Are you asking how to mix and match commandlets in a script?  **Stack Overflow**.

Comment: Is this recommendation still up-to-date? SF's help page says ["Don't ask about... Anything in a home or development environment"](https://arc.net/l/quote/tpavwxgf)

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

Are you a "system administrator and desktop support professional" or someone "who manage[s] or maintain[s] computers in a professional capacity."? i.e. is it your **job**?

If yes then ask on Server Fault.

Are you a "computer enthusiast [or] power user."? i.e. is it your **hobby**?

If yes then ask on Super User.

Answer (score 2):

They don't seem to be programming specific; SU or SF may help, but it could well be that it isn't an a perfect fit on any of them.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, if it's about bash, give http://unix.stackexchange.com a shot as well